# How to configure learning switches?

Tags: python, networking, sdn, mininet

I tried to reproduce 3-tiers architecture without using a controller in mininet, using learning switches. I want to enable STP to ping my user hosts but I couldn't find any documentation or something to help me do that.

```
from mininet.topo import Topo

class ThreeTier( Topo ):
    def __init__( self ):
        Topo.__init__( self )

        # Add hosts and switches
        Switch1 = self.addSwitch('s1')
        Switch2 = self.addSwitch('s2')
        Switch3 = self.addSwitch('s3')
        Switch4 = self.addSwitch('s4')
        Switch5 = self.addSwitch('s5')
        Switch6 = self.addSwitch('s6')
        Switch7 = self.addSwitch('s7')

        Host1 = self.addHost('h1')
        Host2 = self.addHost('h2')

        # Adding links
        #Switch1 Switch2 Switch3 Switch4 are access layer switches
        #Switch5 Switch6 are aggregation layer switches
        #Switch7 is a core layer switch 

        self.addLink( Switch1, Switch5 )
        self.addLink( Switch2, Switch5 )
        self.addLink( Switch3, Switch5 )
        self.addLink( Switch4, Switch5 )

        self.addLink( Switch1, Switch6 )
        self.addLink( Switch2, Switch6 )
        self.addLink( Switch3, Switch6 )
        self.addLink( Switch4, Switch6 )


        self.addLink( Switch5, Switch7 )
        self.addLink( Switch6, Switch7 )

        self.addLink( Host1, Switch1 )
        self.addLink( Host2, Switch3 )
topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: ThreeTier() ) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure they can work without a controller set failMode to standalone and to enable STP set stp to True.

Like this:

```
Switch1 = self.addSwitch('s1', failMode='standalone', stp=True)
Switch2 = self.addSwitch('s2', failMode='standalone', stp=True)
Switch3 = self.addSwitch('s3', failMode='standalone', stp=True)
Switch4 = self.addSwitch('s4', failMode='standalone', stp=True)
Switch5 = self.addSwitch('s5', failMode='standalone', stp=True)
Switch6 = self.addSwitch('s6', failMode='standalone', stp=True)
Switch7 = self.addSwitch('s7', failMode='standalone', stp=True)
```

PS: I am currently working on a web page where you can do all this in GUI (enabling STP is as easy as clicking a checkbox) and then simply export a script. You can try it out on https://thomaash.github.io/me